# auto run a bat script in windows 7 at login

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, virtual-machine, autorun

I have recently acquired a windows 7 laptop from my late grandmother.
I have been using it for work and other things. I decided to create a VM using VirtualBox And now I want to create a user on the (Windows 7 Host) machine so that when I log into that user it autoruns a .bat script to start the VM. To make it clear I only want to run it only if the user "VM" logs in and not my normal user and it would be super awesome if it would autostart in full screen. I have a shortcut on my desktop that executes the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe" --comment "VM" --startvm "12dada4d-    9cfd-4aa7-8353-20b4e455b3fa"
```

but how do I make an autorun.bat when I log into the User "VM"?

Comment: Why don't you log in as the "VM" user, and add a shortcut to the batch file in the "VM" user's Startup group on the Start Menu?  The solution seems too easy...  Perhaps I'm missing part of the problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To run the batch file when the `VM` user logs in:

Drag the shortcut--the one that's currently on your desktop--(or the batch file itself) to Start - All Programs - Startup.  Now when you login as that user, it will launch the batch file.

Another way to do the same thing is to save the shortcut or the batch file in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`.

As far as getting it to run full screen, it depends a bit what you mean.  You can have it launch maximized by editing your batch file like this:

```
start "" /max "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe" --comment "VM" --startvm "12dada4d-9cfd-4aa7-8353-20b4e455b3fa"
```

But if VirtualBox has a truly full-screen mode (where it hides even the taskbar), you'll have to look for a command-line parameter on VirtualBox.exe.  I'm not familiar with that product.

Comment: That worked! Well sorta. I dragged the bat file into startup and I can run it by double clicking and it works just fine but when I log in it brings up a windows that says "Unable to start VM"

Comment: Well now I managed to get it working. Thanks! I don't know what I did it just started working.

Comment: Windows refuses to let me put a copy (shortcut or otherwise) in the Startup folder, either using the Start Menu (I get the red NO icon) or navigating with the file explorer (I get a message saying I can't do that, and offering to create the shortcut on my desktop, which is of course useless). Any thoughts on why? I am the sole user, so presumably I have all permissions.

Comment: Never presume you have all permissions!  :-)  You likely need admin rights; check that your user is running as administrator.  Try right-clicking the Windows Explorer icon (or shift-right-click) and choose Run as Administrator.

Comment: I open notepad++ as administrator. Then I proceed to the path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup and open the file.

Comment: Great! I was not able to do this with task scheduler, but this startup folder works properly.

Answer (score 9):

I hit this question looking for how to run batch scripts during user logon on a standalone windows server (workgroup not in domain). I found the answer in using group policy.

1. gpedit.msc
2. user configuration->administrative templates->system->logon->run these programs at user logon
3. add batch scripts.
4. you can add them using `cmd /k mybatchfile.cmd` if you want the command window to stay (on desktop) after batch script have finished.
5. gpupdate - to update the group policy.

Answer (score 2):

Just enable parsing of the autoexec.bat in the registry, using [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/124551).

```
:: works only on windows vista and earlier 
Run REGEDT32.EXE.
Modify the following value within HKEY_CURRENT_USER: 

Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ParseAutoexec 

1 = autoexec.bat is parsed
0 = autoexec.bat is not parsed
```

Comment: This isn't for Windows 7 normally I'd be fine trying something designed for an old version but I don't want to brick the registry.

Comment: Especially since this is quite a few versions behind (Windows NT (Which ran between '93 and '96))

Comment: @Cagentdog - your right, it only works up through windows Vista.  might not work on Windows 7.  Thanks for the catch.