# Auto run ruby script on windows start

Tags: windows, autorun

I've written a ruby script.

The script gets mysites alexa rank and save that values on a text file. But now I have to run this script manually. Can I automate this? For example I want to autorun this script on Windows start or set cronjob. Is it possible?

My script:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rexml/document'
require 'date'


url = 'http://www.example.com'

xml_data = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&data=snbamz&url='+url)).body
doc = REXML::Document.new(xml_data)

doc.elements.each('ALEXA/SD/POPULARITY') do |ele|
    $alexaValue =  ele.attributes["TEXT"]
    break
end

$today  = Date.today
$echo   =  "#{$today} - #{$alexaValue} - #{url} \n"


File.open("alexa.txt", 'a+') {|f| f.write($echo) }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why is it different from running anything else on windows start or as a cronjob?

Comment: Instead of asking "Is it possible?" (to which the correct answer is "Yes") could you please explain what is preventing you using e.g. Windows Task Manager or adding to Start/Startup menu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [auto run a bat script in windows 7 at login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087694/auto-run-a-bat-script-in-windows-7-at-login)

Comment: i dont now how can i automate and what is the correct way to do this, i do not write any ruby code before

Comment: If you know how to run it manually - simply create a `bat` file that does it, and make a shortcut to it in the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`, like the post above suggests...

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut of cmd.exe and put it in your Start Menu's Startup folder.

In the shortcut's properties, find the Target field and put this in it.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K "ruby C:\Users\username\Documents\rubyscript.rb"
```

Execute it and make sure it works. Then it should work on startup.