# starting laravel app on startup

Tags: laravel, shell, cmd, homestead

I have a laptop for sole development. I shut down my PC when I'm done. It's very annoying when every time I turn on my laptop I have to go to homestead folder and do vagrant up and wait for a minute or two, is there anyway I can automate this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [auto run a bat script in windows 7 at login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087694/auto-run-a-bat-script-in-windows-7-at-login)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a shortcut with the **Target** pointing to something similar to `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -- C:\Vagrant\homestead\v-up.sh` and set **Start in** to `C:\Vagrant\homestead`.

Create the `v-up.sh` file at `C:\Vagrant\homestead`. The content of this file should have only `vagrant up`.

Now add the shortcut to the start up folder of **Windows 7** at `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.